# How to write algorithms?

Tags: ds.algorithms, soft-question, research-practice, paper-review, writing

Reading research articles in theoretical computer science, I noticed that people often describe their algorithms in an **enumerative way** (i.e., they enumerate the steps of their algorithm and use "go to" like phrases to jump back or forward to another step, thus avoiding explicit loops). I mean something like this:

> 1. Step: Do ...
> 2. Step: If ..., go back to step 1. Else, do ...
> 3. Do ...

This is in contrast to pseudocode that is written more in the style of **source code** of some structured programming language, like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue). With this approach, one tends to avoid "go to" statements, which are [considered harmful in programming](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf). I wonder to what extent the criticism of go to statements applies also to the presentation of algorithms in theoretical computer science (outside of programming). I think if one uses something like [Hoare logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic) to prove the correctness of some algorithm, it seems avoiding go to statements is the thing to do.

On the other side, I feel that the enumerative way of describing an algorithm has the advantage that whole algorithm is neatly split into a few chunks, which makes it often conceptually easier for me to read the algorithm, whereas the source code approach often contains many nested loops with many indentations making the algorithm hard to read.

Now I wonder, and this is my big question: Which of the two approaches (enumerative vs source code approach) do you think is more appropriate and suitable in research of theoretical computer science? Which style should be used in research articles? What are the advantages and disadvantages of the two approaches?

Comment: Why do you think that program logics cannot deal with control-flow commands like `goto`? That may have been the case in the 1960s but it's no longer the case today, and moreover, correctness arguments in algo papers tend to be informal, rather than using the rigour of Hoare logic (whether that's a good thing or not is a different question). As to which style to use, how about *When in Rome, do as the Romans do*: the fact that most algo papers use the "enumerative way" is a pretty good indication that it works well for algorithm description. The "style of source code" is more verbose.

Comment: "Why do you think that program logics cannot deal with control-flow commands like goto?" Could you please give the exact quote from my post you are refering to?

Comment: @MartinBerger: Concerning your answer "As to which style to use, how about When in Rome, do as the Romans do: the fact that most algo papers use the "enumerative way" is a pretty good indication that it works well for algorithm description. The "style of source code" is more verbose.", I am very thankful! :-)

Comment: Note that usually you need to number the lines of your algorithm *anyway*, so that you can refer to individual steps in the text (e.g., in the proof of correctness).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: This is clear to me. However, even if the lines of the source code style pseudocode are also numbered, the styles are significantly different. So what style of writing algorithms do you prefer?

Comment: I don't get to write actual explicit algorithms in my papers very often, but I'd say I'm happy to use whatever style that makes the specific algorithm easier to read and understand.

Comment: I am actually sceptical about one style clearly dominating the other. I have done both, and I try to use the style that makes my algorithm and proofs as clear as possible. I tend to prefer pseudocode if the logic of the algorithm is somewhat complicated.